# Disable web part only when browsing SharePoint 2010 site in Chrome

Tags: web-part, list-view, branding

Is it possible to hide a web-part only when user browse the site within Chrome?

I checked "Chrome State" - minimized, "Chrome Type" - none, the first sets web-part minimized both in IE and Chrome, the latter do not hides the web-part in Chrome, using easy-tabs script.

I am wondering if there is any jQuery which can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can check browser with javascript as :

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

And you can hide/disable web part as :

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
document.getElementByID('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4').style.display="none";
</script>
```

MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4 is the id of web part.

Comment: Hi Aanchal, the browser check works, however the display "none" does not work in Chrome.

Comment: Have you replaced the code with your webpart I'd?

Comment: Yes, I replaced the code.

Comment: Can you share your code?